# Will work VGA->HDMI via 2 adapters?

Tags: hdmi, vga, dvi

I want buy new graphics card which have DVI and HDMI output but i have old monitors (first:HDMI, second:VGA) also i owns reduction VGA->DVI and DVI->HDMI and so i have question - will it work?

Monitor cable: [VGA](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/29/Male_VGA_connector.jpg)

Reduction #1: [VGA->DVI](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31dgGNBvrxL.jpg)

Reduction #2: [DVI->HDMI](https://images10.newegg.com/ProductImageCompressAll300/12K-00AB-00039-01.jpg)

HDMI output from graphics card: [HDMI](http://www.hd.cz/img/konektory/vga/hdmi-female-connector.jpg)

Will this connecion  work?

I don't want buy new adapter direct [VGA->HDMI](http://www.ncst.co.za/home/images/stories/virtuemart/product/ghdmivga.jpg) because secondary monitor is very old and soon want buy new...

Comment: All your connections are listed the wrong way round. You're going **from** HDMI or DVI **to** VGA... which makes it an entirely different question.

Comment: Ok and anserwer that different quetion is?

Comment: @LajdákMarek Please reconsider my answer to the original question. The second question is a matter of personal preferences. There is no other solution than to convert the signal.

Comment: If you have DVI and HDMI outputs available, and assuming you can use both independently (can you?), and you need HDMI for the first monitor, why are you looking for an HDMI connection for the VGA monitor rather than a DVI connection?

Comment: Because i have 2 monitors. DVI and VGA. But it is gone. Graphics cards I have already bought and VGA monitor is too old and have defetcts so it will go to the Recycle Bin :) Main answer is - no it's not possible connect graphics card -> monitor via this reductions listed in question there must be 'converter' but I do not want to buy this to old monitor.

Answer (score 1):

No.

VGA is analog connection.
HDMI is a digital connection.

You should get a converter device from VGA to HDMI. They are sort of a box like device. You can find them easily on amazon or ebay by searching VGA to HDMI

I see that you don't want to buy a new adapter but you have to ask yourself am I going to pay ~20$ and get to use that monitor or do I wait until I can buy the new monitor. Its just a matter of preference.

Comment: The free video output is DVI, the monitor input is VGA.  A DVI to VGA (or HDMI to VGA) converter is needed, not VGA to anything.